# Getting ValueError: Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns' on passing a list of lables as 'columns' parameter of drop() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was passing an Index type variable (`Pandas.Index`) containing the labels of columns I want to drop from my DataFrame and it was working correctly. It was Index type because I was extracting the column names based on certain condition from the DataFrame itself.

Afterwards, I needed to add another column name to that list, so I converted the Index object to a Python list so I could append the additional label name. But on passing the list as columns parameter to the `drop()` method on the Dataframe, I now keep getting the error :

`ValueError: Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns'`

How to resolve this error?

The code I use is like this:

```
unique_count = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
redundant_columns = unique_count[unique_count == 1].index.values.tolist()
redundant_columns.append('DESCRIPTION')
print(redundant_columns)
df.drop(columns=redundant_columns, inplace=True)

Out: None
```

I found why the error is occurring. After the `append()` statement, `redundant_columns` is becoming `None`. I don't know why. I would love if someone can explain why this is happening?

Comment: `L = ['col1','col2']` and then `drop(L)` does not work? Can you show how use `drop` ?

Comment: Hmmm, unfortuantely I cannot simulate it, so no idea how solve it. Problem should be in data or in pandas/python.

Comment: @jezrael It's a good solution, so why delete it? I am waiting, will mark an answer as accepted later

Comment: I only think you are not interested, but OK, not remove it.

Comment: @jezrael I am interested in your solution, very elegant. I haven't used it in my code because I am trying to avoid copying as much as possible, memory optimizing so i don't run out of memory. So I am doing inplace operations as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your solution working nice.

Another solution for remove columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('bbbbbb'),
                   'DESCRIPTION':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'DESCRIPTION':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  C  D DESCRIPTION  E
0  b  7  1           a  5
1  b  8  3           a  3
2  b  9  5           a  6
3  b  4  7           b  9
4  b  2  1           b  2
5  b  3  0           b  4

mask = df.nunique().ne(1)
mask['DESCRIPTION'] = False
df = df.loc[:, mask]

print (df)
   C  D  E
0  7  1  5
1  8  3  3
2  9  5  6
3  4  7  9
4  2  1  2
5  3  0  4
```

Explanation:

1. First get length of unique values by `nunique` and compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal
2. Change boolean mask - column `DESCRIPTION` to `False` for always remove
3. Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

**Details**:

```
print (df.nunique())

A              1
C              6
D              5
DESCRIPTION    2
E              6
dtype: int64

mask = df.nunique().ne(1)
print (mask)
A              False
C               True
D               True
DESCRIPTION     True
E               True

mask['DESCRIPTION'] = False
print (mask)
A              False
C               True
D               True
DESCRIPTION    False
E               True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: @SushovanMandal - Just test your solution and working nice :(

Comment: Can you provide a description for your solution above?

Comment: @SushovanMandal - Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks for this. But the code i posted in question is still not working. I gave a print statement in middle and the `redundant_columns` is become `None` after the `.append()` statement. Why is that?

Comment: @SushovanMandal - It is really weird, can you check this `L = [1,4]
L.append(7)
print (L)` ?

Comment: and `redundant_columns = unique_count[unique_count == 1].index.values.tolist()` return list?

Comment: I check solution with `source empty list and also working nice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169585/discussion-between-sushovan-mandal-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

After trying around, this got fixed by using numpy.ndarray instead of plain Python list, although I don't know why.

In my trials, using plain Python List is giving ValueError, pandas.Index or numpy.ndarray type object containing the labels is working fine. So I went with np.ndarray as that is appendable.

Current working code:

```
    unique_count = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
    redundant_columns: np.ndarray = unique_count[unique_count == 1].index.values
    redundant_columns = np.append(redundant_columns, 'DESCRIPTION')
    self.full_data.drop(columns=redundant_columns, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using .remove in the line of initialization:

```
myNewList = [i for i in myOldList].remove('Last Item')
```

myNewList would become none type. Using .tolist() in a separate column might help you:

```
redundant_columns = unique_count[unique_count == 1].index.values
redundant_columns.tolist()
redundant_columns.append('DESCRIPTION')
```