# Python Pipeline returns NaN Scores When Used in Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I want to create a pipeline with sklearn including some preprocessing steps and a final step with a model to fit to the data. I use this pipeline to get scores by cross-validation. Later on I would like to use the pipeline in `GridSearchCV` for parameters optimization.

As to now, the preprocessing steps include:

- One step in which some colums are dropped, using a `ColumnsRemoval()` class that I created,
- One step which is specific to each feature type (categorical or numerical). To simplify in the example below I have just included a `StandardScaler()` for numerical features and `OneHotEncoder()` for categorical features.

The problem is that the scores I get are all `nan`. It runs quite fast and it seems as if empty arrays where being passed into the model:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
import numpy as np

# Create random dataframe
num_data = np.random.random_sample((5,4))
cat_data = ['good','bad','fair','excellent','bad']
col_list_stack = ['SalePrice','Id','TotalBsmtSF','GrdLivArea']
data = pd.DataFrame(num_data, columns = col_list_stack)

data['Quality'] = cat_data

X_train = data.drop(labels = ['SalePrice'], axis = 1)
y_train = data['SalePrice']

#------------------------------------------------------------#
# create a custom transformer to remove columns
class ColumnsRemoval(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, skip = False, remove_cols = ['Id','TotalBsmtSF']):
        self._remove_cols = remove_cols
        self._skip = skip
        
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self
                
    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        if not self._skip:
            return X.drop(labels = self._remove_cols,axis = 1)
        else:
            return X

#------------------------------------------------------------#
# PIPELINE and cross-validation        
# Preprocessing steps common to numerical and categorical data
preprocessor_common = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('remove_features', ColumnsRemoval())])

# Separated preprocessing steps
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[    
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor_by_cat = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, ['GrdLivArea']),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, ['Quality'])], remainder = 'passthrough')

# Full pipeline with model
pipe = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor_common', preprocessor_common),
                    ('preprocessor_by_cat', preprocessor_by_cat),
                  ('model', LinearRegression())])

# Use cross validation to obtain scores
scores = cross_validate(pipe, X_train, y_train,
            scoring = ["neg_mean_squared_error","r2"], cv = 4)
```

I have tried the following:

- Using only one of the preprocessing steps plus the model in the pipeline. When I use `preprocessor_by_cat` + `model` steps in the pipeline, I get score values. Using `preprocessor_common` + `model` steps gives `nan` scores as well
- Perform both preprocessing steps in a pipeline (`preprocessor_common`+`preprocessor_by_cat`), `.fit_transform()` the training data, and then send it to cross_validate(), roughly as below:

```py
pipe = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor_common', preprocessor_common),
                            ('preprocessor_by_cat', preprocessor_by_cat),
                      ])
X_processed = pipe.fit_transform(X_train)

# Use cross validation to obtain scores
scores = cross_validate(LinearRegression(), X_processed, y_train,
            scoring = ["neg_mean_squared_error","r2"], cv = 4)
```

From my understanding, doing the preprocessing in a pipeline or doing the preprocessing + the model to the pipeline are the same, which is why I believe it is a problem to get `NaN` values.

I hope the problem is clear, congratulations if you made it this far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You need to redefine the `__init()__` function of your custom `ColumnsRemoval` as passing a Python list as default value will result in an error. One possible solution:

```
class ColumnsRemoval(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, skip=False, remove_cols=None):
        if remove_cols is None:
            remove_cols = ['Id', 'TotalBsmtSF']
        self._remove_cols = remove_cols
        self._skip = skip

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        if not self._skip:
            return X.drop(labels=self._remove_cols, axis=1)
        else:
            return X
```

With this, your pipeline should work as expected.

---

**Background**

I ran your MWE and got the following error:

```
FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.
```

It was related to the following line of your custom `ColumnsRemoval`:

```
return X.drop(labels=self._remove_cols, axis=1)
```

which threw the error:

```
ValueError: Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns'
```

It seems to be a known issue when passing a standard Python list to the `drop()` function and is discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979122/getting-valueerror-need-to-specify-at-least-one-of-labels-index-or-column). The solution is to instead pass e.g. a `numpy` array or `pandas` index object. Another solution, which I proposed, is to not set a default for `remove_cols` in the function definition but to assign it in the function body. This works as well.

It does not look like anybody really knows why this is happening. Sorry that I cannot elaborate more on the actual reason (more than happy if anybody can add). But the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more the issue that you mention. I have been running some tests with another custom transformer  in which I use a threshold with a `float` value. If I provide a default value in the `__init__()` of the `Transformer`, I run into the same problem of obtaining `nan` as scores. Is that a known issue as well, or the issue is in principle only related to using a `list` as default? (and thus the problem is somewhere else in my code).
Thanks!

Comment: Using a `list` as a default for function parameters is in general strongly discouraged. `list` is a mutable data type in Python and thus, just serves as a container with references to the actual objects it contains. This can cause all sorts of problems and should therefore be avoided. It is likely the error you encountered here is related to this. Assigning an immutable data type like `float` as a default on the other hand is a standard thing to do and should not cause any problems by itself. So the intuition is that in the other case you describe the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks again. I found where the problem was when using a `float`, and that also solved my problem with the `ColumnsRemoval` class. I have posted it in a new answer, for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was. I have been doing some further tests, also using a `float` instead of a list as default value.

As detailed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html), under the **Instantiantion** section:

> the object's attributes used in `__init__()` should have exactly the
> name of the argument in the constructor.

So what I did was to use the same object attribute names than the parameter names passed in `__init__()`, and now everything works well. For example:

```py
class ColumnsRemoval(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, threshold = 0.9)
        self.threshold = threshold
```

Using `self._threshold` (note the `_` before `threshold`) had a strange behavior, in some cases the object was being used with the provided value (or the default one) but in other cases `self._threshold` was being set to `None`. This also allows using a `list` as default value to pass through `__init__()` (although using a `list` as default should be avoided, see afsharov's answer for details)